# what is difference between async private and private async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I am just wondering that what is basic difference between `async private` and `private async` methods. Which declarations is good to **implement**? Does it effect on any **performances** ?
Any one knows ?

Answer (score 6):

There's no difference at all - use whichever style you like.

Answer (score 3):

They are both the same. Access Modifiers and Modifiers can be in any order, the Compiler doesn't care which order you put them in. Usually the Access Modifier is put before the Modifier.

```
public const // Is the same as:
const public

private static // Is the same as:
static private
```